# Custom Implementation of IClientStore

Tags: identityserver4

We are using EntityFramework Core with Identity Server4 to store configuration data. Do we need custom implementation of IClientStore(i.e FindClientByIdAsync) interface to fetch client from database?

```
 public class CustomClientStore : IClientStore
{
    const string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;database=IdentityServer4.Quickstart.EntityFramework-2.0.0;trusted_connection=yes;";
    public Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ConfigurationDbContext>();

        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        var _context = new ConfigurationDbContext(options.Options, new ConfigurationStoreOptions());

        var result = _context.Clients.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId).FirstOrDefault();

        return Task.FromResult(result.ToModel());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to roll your own. An Entity Framework Core implementation of IClientStore already exists in the IdentityServer4.EntityFramework package.

This can be registered like so:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
  //.AddInMemoryClients(new List<Client>())
  .AddConfigurationStore(options => options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => 
      builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

See example repository for full code example:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/src/EntityFramework/host

Comment: ok thanks Scott, if we have to add client's dynamically then should we create an endpoint for that?

Comment: There's a spec on dynamic client registration and unfortunately IdentityServer does not implement it. So yes, you'll need a new endpoint. https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html

Comment: Is there any online sample that doing the same?(i.e dynamic client registration)

Comment: Not that I know of. Let me know if you find one though!

Comment: Default client store is weak. It only allows for findbyid by simply doing a firstordefault on the context.  I fail to see the point.