# How to define custom IClientStore to support 3rd Party Developers

Tags: identityserver4

I can't seem to find in the Identity Server 4 documentation on how to support Clients that are 3rd party developers and not just applications.

How can I implement a custom IClientStore to support clients that are actually developers connecting to my APIs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[The official docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/clients.html) mention this:

> At runtime, clients are retrieved via an implementation of the `IClientStore`. This allows loading them from arbitrary data sources like config files or databases. For this document we will use the in-memory version of the client store. You can wire up the in-memory store in `ConfigureServices` via the `AddInMemoryClients` extensions method.

This suggests that you should provide your own implemenation. I'd presume this as well, given [this similar (perhaps even duplicate?) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48436423/419956), and that one of the IDS4 authors [seems (at first glance) to suggest something similar](https://damienbod.com/2017/12/30/using-an-ef-core-database-for-the-identityserver4-configuration-data/).

Bottom line: roll your own `IClientStore` implementation.

Comment: Thanks @jeroen but I'm curious to see how to create a client dynamic in a sense it not another application  accessing the APIs but rather a 3rd part developer so not sure what type of grant goes for those 3ed party developers. Thanks

Comment: Huh? I don't follow? If you want others to create `Client` entries on your Identity Server, then you need to provide a UI for them to do CRUD, and provide a store as in the answer I propose. - You might need to clarify your question, possibly come up with concrete examples and an example bit of code as well...

Comment: Yes, a developer will create an account at my side and will be given a secret and ID. Then, they need to connect and access APIs via Identity server. So there is no actually a client configured, just a 3rd party developer trying to access the resource API. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I'm sorry, but for me that's not enough clarification. For me it'd have to be more extensive, with concrete examples, and preferably even code or pseudocode. I suggest editing it into the question too, because now it's buried here as comments and others won't see it.